# How can I get private photos in a Flickr photo set?

Tags: ios, flickr

I have a private Flickr photoset. I own that photoset. I want to use that photoset in my iOS application, but I can't get photo list user `photoset.getPhotos` Flickr API. It return error "Photoset not found". If I public that photoset, I can get. But I don't want to public.

How can I get photos from my private photoset, without authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

You can't fetch the photos unless you are authenticated via a Flickr app. You can easily create your own Flickr app that only you use, and with that authorize your Flickr account and you'll have API access to your private photos.

Comment: But I want create an app, for every one use. It load photo from my private album (because I don't want public for every one use browser, without my app). I found some app, they can do that. In the URL that app call, has "auth_token " param. I don't know how they get it, and how to handle when auth_token expire